# Angular scripts missing in Yeoman-Angular generated app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, bower

I have generated an app using Yeoman-Angular Generator, but the angular.js and other Angular files are missing from the project. I can see these dependencies in the bower.json file as follows:
{
  "name": "mi-portfolio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.6"
  }
}

But, the JS files themselves aren't available. So, I get the 'angular is not defined' error when running the app. I ran the commands as given in the Yeoman-Angular Generator's documentation. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `bower install`, sometimes this fails when running Yeoman so you've gotta attempt manually.