# Yeoman Angular generator - bower_components missing in app folder

Tags: yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

Im on windows and when I use Angular generator to scaffold my application `bower_components` is missing in `app` directory - instead its in the root directory

This is my `app` directory after fresh scaffolding:

[image: <code>app</code> directory]

So I have to manually put bower components in the `app` directory...

Any ideas why is this happening?

P.S in bower.json I have:

```
"appPath": "app"
```

But that option is not respected, when I run `bower install` it doesnt add `bower_components` into the `app` directory.

Comment: there is file ` bower.json` on the directory? try to run `bower install`, but you should already install bower , check in here [**bower**](https://github.com/bower/bower)

Comment: Hi I just updated my question - even runnign bower install doesnt fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made it work - edited `.bowerrc`

```
{
  "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

and then `bower install`.

Now all dependencies are in `app` directory.

Answer (score 0):

try edit your bower.json file, then run `bower install`

```
{ 
    "name": "mi-portfolio", 
    "version": "0.0.0", 
    "directory": "bower_components/"
    "dependencies": 
    { 
        "angular": "1.2.6", 
        "json3": "~3.2.6", 
        "es5-shim": "~2.1.0", 
        "jquery": "~1.10.2", 
        "bootstrap": "~3.0.3", 
        "angular-cookies": "1.2.6", 
        "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6" 
    }, 
    "devDependencies": 
    { 
        "angular-mocks": "1.2.6", 
        "angular-scenario": "1.2.6" 
    }
}
```

look here  [bower code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189905/angular-scripts-missing-in-yeoman-angular-generated-app)